# SQL Server 2019 service won't start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I just downloaded and installed SQL Server 2019 on my Windows 10 machine. But I was not able to connect to it via SSMS.

I went to the services and saw that "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" service is not started. When I start the service it shows message

> The SQL Server mssqlserver service on local computer started and stopped

I checked for event log and there is an error:

> SQL Server is terminating a system or background task Logwriter Task due to errors in starting up the task (setup state 8).

In SQL ErrorLog I can see following lines that I think are relevant.

> Error: 17312, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2019-11-04 01:12:49.11 spid2s      SQL Server is terminating a system or background task AzureLeaseRenewalTask due to errors in starting up the task (setup state 8).
>   2019-11-04 01:12:49.11 spid1s      CImageHelper::Init () Version-specific dbghelp.dll is not used
>   2019-11-04 01:12:49.11 spid2s      Error: 28709, Severity: 16, State: 19.
>   2019-11-04 01:12:49.11 spid2s      Dispatcher was unable to create new thread.
>   2019-11-04 01:12:49.13 spid1s      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0007.txt
>   2019-11-04 01:12:49.13 spid1s      SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 1 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.

Comment: Have a look at the logs. If you don't understand the error, post them here

Comment: @Larnu i went through sql ErrorLog file and saw some relevant info that i added in description. Please let me know if i can help providing more information.